# Erro CS1526 & CS8032

Tags: c#, unity3d

Pela tradução do erro diz que tenho de colocar uma ")" ao final do "type" porem já
 existe um ")" ao final do "type" ja tentei mudar para "[ ]" porém não funcionou 
tentei colocar 2 ")" como ja vi em outros códigos porem também não funcionou

> Assets/Scripts/Dinheiro.cs(14,71): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type

o segundo erro nao tentei nada.

> Assets/Scripts/Dinheiro.cs(14,93): error CS8032: Internal compiler error during parsing, Run with -v for details

o codigo :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Dinheiro : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0, -4);
    public Vector3 velocity3D = new Vector3(0, -4, 0);
    public float range = 4;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //rigidbody2D.velocity = velocity;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x – range * Random.value, transform.position.y , transform.position.z);

    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position += velocity3D * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Dá erro em qual linha?

Comment: Vc tem certeza que salvou o arquivo antes de tentar rodar novamente? Aparentemente tá tudo certo. Teste trocando a linha 14 por `transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);` e veja se o erro persiste. Depois vá acrescentando o restante pouco a pouco.

Comment: o erro é na linha 14

Comment: Qual é a linha 14, o número, nós vimos, mas não temos como saber onde é. Pra mim a linha 14 é uma linha em branco. E nenhuma linha tem algo relacionado ao erro apresentado.

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente parece tudo certo, mas eu percebi que o sinal de menos da expressão "transform.position.x – range" está um pouco maior, usei o https://dotnetfiddle.net/ (https://dotnetfiddle.net/sp7ZCA) e realmente ele indicou erro nesse sinal como caracter inesperado. E por conta disso ele espera um fecha parenteses aberto do construtor, corrija esse caracter com o '-' certo que deve funcionar de boa!

Olha a comparação:

```
transform.position.x – range //Seu sinal de menos
transform.position.x - range //Sinal de menos correto
```

Comment: +1 Muito bem observado! :)